# Get canonical form from list entity

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework, using the LUIS API, and in it I have an entity that's a closed list. 
And I wanted to programmatically get its canonical form value when my bot catches an intent with that entity. But all I seem able to do is to get the value that the user typed, the synonym found.

```
foreach (var entity in result.Entities)
{
   await context.PostAsync($"{entity.Type}: {entity.Entity}");
}
```

Comment: I think you will find it in the [Resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.luis.models.entityrecommendation.resolution?view=botbuilder-3.11.0#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Luis_Models_EntityRecommendation_Resolution) property.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43358558/luis-closed-list-entities) has some more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to do it, using the comments and expanding on the answer from JasonSowers, had to travel on the dictionary and use a couple of casts but got around to it finally:

```
foreach (var entity in result.Entities)
{
   var dict = entity.Resolution.Values.GetEnumerator();
   dict.MoveNext();
   var valuesList = (List<object>)dict.Current;
   var canonicalForm = (string)valuesList[0];

   await context.PostAsync($"{canonicalForm}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the dictionary contained in `Entities.Resolution` Dictionary  Specifically the array of string that you will find in `Entities.Resolution.Values;`

This [documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d7/d66/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_luis_1_1_models_1_1_entity_recommendation.html) should help you

Using your code example:

```
foreach (var entity in result.Entities)
{
   await context.PostAsync($"{entity.Resolution.Values}");
}
```

Comment: Found a way to do it expanding on your solution, in order to really get the string value of the canonical form, put my complete answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected string GetCanonicalValue(string entityName, LuisResult intentContext)
    {
        List<EntityRecommendation> intentList = intentContext.Entities.Where(x => x.Type.Equals(entityName)).ToList();
        string canonicalForm = string.Empty;
        foreach (EntityRecommendation entity in intentList)
        {
            IEnumerator<object> dict = entity.Resolution.Values.GetEnumerator();
            dict.MoveNext();
            List<object> valuesList = (List<object>)dict.Current;
            canonicalForm = (string)valuesList[0];
        }
        return canonicalForm;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain your code a bit (i.e. what was wrong with code in question, how your code is more correct...)? This can help users viewing your answer understand it better.